# Subtract one column from multiple columns in r

Tags: r

I have this data frame with date, Mkt, Rf and then 237 variables which have numbered names. I want to subtract the variable Rf from all 230 numbered variables. I have tried

`df[,4:240] = df[,4:240] - df[,3]`

but it doesn't seem to work. I'm assuming I would have to create a loop for this type of subtraction but I don't know how I would add the Rf column to subtract inside the loop.

```
|  |Date      |Mkt  |Rf   |10094|10098|10115|...
|:-|:---------|:----|:----|:----|:----|:----|...
|1 |01-01-1997|0.056|0.006|0.002|0.034|0.564|...
|2 |01-02-1997|0.653|0.009|0.009|0.052|0.445|...
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't seem to work"? Is there an error message? A discrepancy between expected and actual results? In either case can you show it?

Comment: If it is a data.frame, your code should have worked.  Perhaps you have a `tibble` or `data.table`, in that case you would need `df[[3]]` instead of `df[,3]` as `df[,3]` would still be a tibble/data.table with a single column instead of a vector

Comment: Try: `df[,4:240] = df[,4:240] - unlist(df[,3])`

Answer (score 0):

You could use this simple `for` loop:

```
for(column in 4:240){
  df[,column]=df[,column]-df[,3]
}
```